# How to use pgcrypto `crypt` function with Go's (*sql.Tx).Exec function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, psql, pgcrypto

I would like to be able to use the encryption provided by the PostgreSQL extension pgcrypto from within my go program. Consider this code snippet:

```golang
_, err = tx.Exec("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, crypt(?, gen_salt('bf', 8)))", u.Username, u.Email, u.Password)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not create user in database:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
```

I receive the following log message: `Could not create user in database: pq: syntax error at or near ","`.

When I manually execute this statement

```sql
INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES ('test', 'test@test.org', crypt('12345', gen_salt('bf', 8)));
```

it successfully creates a row in the database.
How can I make the crypt function work from within Go?

Comment: Isn't it that PostgreSQL uses `$1`, `$2` etc for parameter placeholders (instead of `?`)?

Comment: Thank you, I could not see this simple mistake! It now works with the correct parameter placeholders